# Rally Excel Add On query

Tags: excel, rally

I am attempting to reproduce a query that works in Rally (get the results I want) In the Excel add on but not having success.

The query from Rally is

```
(((State != Closed) AND (CreationDate >= 2015-02-10)) AND ((Tags contains "Regression") OR (Name contains "Regression") OR (Name contains Regress)))
```

When I enter this into the filter field for the new query in Excel with the 
get an error that says

```
Cannot Parse.  Error parsing expression -- expected ")" but saw OR instead.
```

The OR values work in Rally itself not sure what the problem is with OR in excel

Karen

Comment: You can try this, `(((State != Closed) AND (CreationDate >= 2015-02-10)) AND (((Tags contains "Regression") OR (Name contains "Regression"))OR (Name contains Regress)))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sontya.  I continue to get the error  query failed due to errors.  cannot parse object reference from "Regression".  I have two instances of Regression in the query so changed one to regression to see which one is having the problem.  Run again and its the Tags regression that's throwing the error.

Comment: This works  (((State != Closed) AND (CreationDate >= 2015-02-10)) AND ((Name contains "Regression") OR (Name contains "Regress")))

Comment: any ideas how to add OR (Tag = "Regression")

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following Syntax is what you're looking for. Note the use of `Tags.Name` in the condition on `Tags`:

`(((State != Closed) AND (CreationDate > 2015-02-10)) AND (((Tags.Name contains "Regression") OR (Name contains "Regression")) OR (Name contains "Regress")))`